# Is there any way to check if constructor prop changed and then re-render component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question is there any way to check if constructor prop changed in session storage and according to that re-render component?

Example:

```
export class MainPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.channelId = sessionStorage.getItem('channelId');
    };
  }
    componentDidMount() {
      fetch(`http://url.com/${this.channelId}`,     
            {
             method: 'GET'
            },
           )
    }
```

EDIT: an example where I add an item to session storage:

```
export class ChannelItem extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      channelChange: false,
    };

    this.channelChange = this.channelChange.bind(this);
  }

  channelChange() {
    this.setState({ channelChange: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { item } = this.props;

    if (this.state.channelChange) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('channelId', item.channelId);    
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: By "constructor prop" I assume you simply mean the instance variable `this.channelId`? If so, ***when*** does it change? When do you want to check it?

Comment: @Chris, there is another component "ChannelList", on ListItem click it changes session's storage item to another channel. I want to rerender MainPage component after that session storage item change.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think this is possible. Event listeners on `storage` only trigger if the storage was modified in another web document, not from the same. I would suggest using some kind of state management to solve this, such as redux or Mobx.

Comment: @PrEto if you want to ensure a rerender when yhe session storage variable changes, pass it to MainPage as a prop

Comment: @SrThompson, could you show me an example?

Comment: @PrEto sure, but could you show where and how you're setting/updating sessionStorage for clarity? That would help with the example :)

Comment: @SrThompson, I have added code, where I put item to session storage.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use componentWillReceiveProps(){} life cycle method for it when ever props are change or update it will render

Answer (score 0):

React rerenders automatically either when a prop changes or when state is updated. So in your case, the simplest solution would be passing the `sessionStorage` variable as a prop to `MainPage`. That could be achieved by lifting that state up to a container component

```
export class MainPage extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      fetch(`http://url.com/${this.props.channelId}`,     
            {
             method: 'GET'
            },
           )
    }

    //This lifecycle method gets called every time props or state change
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (prevProps.channelId !== this.props.channelId) {
        fetch(`http://url.com/${this.props.channelId}`,     
            {
             method: 'GET'
            },
           )
      }
    }
    //...
}

export class ChannelItem extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      channelChange: false,
    };

    this.channelChange = this.channelChange.bind(this);
  }

  channelChange() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('channelId', item.channelId); 
    // after setting the sessionStorage value, you call back the parent component to update its state, triggering the rerender
    this.props.onChannelChange();
  }
  //...
}

class SomeContainerComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      channelId: sessionStorage.getItem('channelId'),
    }
  }

  onSessionChange = () => {
    this.setState({ channelId: sessionStorage.getItem('channelId') });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <MainPage channelId={this.state.channelId} />
       <ChannelItem onChannelChange={this.onSessionChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's good solution. But in my case MainPage is Parent and ChannelItem is 5th deep layer child

Comment: You have a couple of alternatives then. You can pass down a callback in the same way I show above, but from the MainPage component. You can introduce a state management library, which I don't recommend except if you have other use cases for it. OR you could trigger a custom event and either subscribe to it on the main page, or just rerender the whole app (I've done this before, it's kind of cumbersome but not impossible)

Comment: So, I guess it's best way to stay with react-redux this time :D